# Panel scrolling in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having bootstrap code as follows

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row ">
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
           <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default" id="fp">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        First Panel
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default" id="sp">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Second Panel
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-3" id="movable-container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                        Movable Panel
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is when I click on panels with id 'sf' or 'sp' then the panel with id
'movable-container' must be aligned horizontally with this panel.

Sample can be seen [here](http://www.bootply.com/avD73XQTb8#)

What I want to achieve is when user clicks on panel with

What I tried to do is get the position of the container I clicked and moving the 'mocable-container' x pixels down where x is the returned position of clicked container. Also the animate() function of jquery is not working multiple times.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the same function for both:

```
$("#sp, #fp").on("click",function(e){
  var pos = $("#movable-container").position().top;
  $('#movable-container').animate({
    'top': $(this).position().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

**[BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/L9PDyLwBs5)**

Comment: My understanding of position() is too novice. Could you enlighten me why it is working? Also if I click on them multiple times, why animation is not applying multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you looking for?

```
$("#sp").on("click",function(e){
  var pos = $("#movable-container").position().top;
      $('#movable-container').animate({
            'top': $(this).position().top
       }, 1000);
});

$("#fp").on("click",function(e){
      $('#movable-container').animate({
            'top': $(this).position().top
       }, 1000);
});
```